# bash - find all .bashrc files and append to them

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find all .bashrc files and append "MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null" to it, to remediate an issue. There are alot of .bashrc files, so can I do something like:

```
find / -type f -name ".bashrc" -exec echo "export MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null" >> {} \;
```

Comment: Why not just edit the global bash configuration file?

Comment: `/etc/profile` is an appropriate place for such environment variables. Be sure to export it, though: `export MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null`.

Comment: I've already updated /etc/skel/.bashrc so for new users, this will be part of their profile. I am trying to remediate user profiles that have already been created.

Comment: @SteveHong You don't have to. Put it in `/etc/profile`, and every any instance of `bash` started as a login shell will source `/etc/profile` regardless of what the user does with their personal configuration files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>>` is executed by the original shell process, it can't use substitution from `find`. And `find` doesn't run its command through a shell, so it can't do output redirection itself.

You need to execute `bash` explicitly so you can use redirection in the command.

```
find / -type f -name '.bashrc' -exec bash -c 'echo export MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null >> "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Thanks - this works.  I did have a typo in my original message, it should have been "export MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null"